# JQuery not working in my angular template

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I'm newbie in angular 2, and first sorry if the question is simple, but I spent whole day to search, and still have no solution. Here my problem:
The JQUERY script in javascript file is running before the element is generated by angular code, that's why the DOM element cannot trigger with my JQUERY function, i.e: click, or change. 
I bought a theme, and all the script action with DOM element they wrote in one file, namely script.js. 
How can I make this file working, I mean do I need run script after all element finish generated by angular 2. If so, how can I do that? 
Thanks.
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: Need examples of your code

Comment: I resolved this problem thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

**check script.js if it executes document.ready remove that and wrap all code in a function** for example

```
mythemeInitiailize(){
   all jquery code goes here
}
```

you can also place all that code in angular service

than in which components you want to use

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
  setTimeout(()=>{
    mythemeInitiailize();
  }, 500)

}
```

Comment: I add the function like your comment in my services, and it has error compile, it seem that angular service cannot call javascript function. 
`ngAfterViewInit(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
      mythemeInitiailize();
    }, 500)
  }`
landing-page.component.ts (38,7): Cannot find name 'mythemeInitiailize'.
webpack: Failed to compile.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your code inside this Angular 2 life hook  `ngAfterViewInit()` if you want to execute your code onLoad

something like:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  // my code
}
```

[Check this link to read more about Angular 2 life hooks](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html)